# Replace anchor text with PHP (and regular expression)

Tags: php, regex, anchor

I have a string that contains a lot of links and I would like to adjust them before they are printed to screen:

I have something like the following:

```
<a href="http://www.dont_replace_this.com">replace_this</a>
```

and would like to end up with something like this

```
<a href="http://www.dont_replace_this.com">replace this</a>
```

Normally I would just use something like:

```
echo str_replace("_"," ",$url);
```

In in this case I can't do that as the URL contains underscores so it breaks my links, the thought was that I could use regular expression to get around this.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't want to adjust the links, but the text.

Comment: Yeah that's correct. I only want to replace the underscores in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will cover most cases, but I suggest you review to make sure that nothing unexpected was missed or changed.

```
 pattern = "/_(?=[^>]*<)/";
 preg_replace($pattern,"",$url);
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, this worked a treat. (Just had to add the $ to the start of the the pattern variable)

Answer (score 4):

Here's the regex: `<a(.+?)>.+?<\/a>`.

What I'm doing is preserving the important dynamic stuff within the anchor tag, and and replacing it with the following function:

```
preg_replace('/<a(.+?)>.+?<\/a>/i',"<a$1>REPLACE</a>",$url);
```

Comment: This is close, however I want to preserver the existing text, but replace all of the underscores with a space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression

```
(>(.*)<\s*/)
```

along with [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) .

**EDIT :**

```
$replaced_text = preg_replace_callback('~(>(.*)<\s*/)~g','uscore_replace', $text);  
function uscore_replace($matches){
   return str_replace('_','',$matches[1]); //try this with 1 as index if it fails try 0, I am not entirely sure
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however I need a little more information about how to use this as I'm fairly clueless at preg_replace!