# Change Wordpress %title variable output in previous_post_link

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using this code in our WordPress theme template to show the previous post which appears to work:  `previous_post_link('%link', '%title', true);`

However, the content of %title includes the entire title of each post, which is very long and messes up the theme formatting.

Is there a way to modify the output of %title to limit to 20 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function modify_title_previous_post_link($link) {
  preg_match('~>\K[^<>]*(?=<)~', $link, $match);  
  $title=$match[0];
  $title = substr($title,0,20);
  $title.="...";
  $link=preg_replace('/<a(.+?)>.+?<\/a>/i',"<a$1>$title</a>",$link); 
  return $link;
}
add_filter('previous_post_link','modify_title_previous_post_link');
```

I'm not that good with regex, so I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29048805/850010) answer for *preg_match* and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7532635/850010) answer for *preg_replace*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of the `preg_match` method.

Is there a reason that you have to pass `'%title'` into `previous_post_link`? The Wordpress function just does a text replacement on it, it's not really a complex macro or anything.

I'd do something more like

```
 $prev_title = $get_previous_post()->post_title;

 if (strlen($prev_title) > 20)
     $prev_title = substr($prev_title , 0, 20) . '...';

 previous_post_link('%link', $prev_title, true);
```

(I'm new to PHP so I might have gotten some syntax wrong, but that's the basic idea)